# How do I choose between values of different types to pass to a polymorphic function?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

Both numbers and strings can be passed with `<<` to cout. How can I use the ternary operator to pass either of these two values to it when they have different types?

For example, this is legal:

```
if(___0607sqrt(a) != 0) {
    cout << "sqrt(" << a << ") = " << ___0607sqrt(a);
} else {
    cout << "sqrt(" << a << ") = " << "?");
}
```

But this isn't:

```
cout << "sqrt(" << a << ") = " << ((___0607sqrt(a) != 0) ? ___0607sqrt(a) : "?");
```

When I try it, I get this error:

```
Error (active)  E0042   operand types are incompatible ("int" and "const char *")   Basic programming   C:\Users\szeva\Desktop\Basic programming\Basic programming\Source.cpp   2316
```

The function ___0607sqrt works well (I checked it already) and returns an int, but just in case, here's its code:

```
int ___0607sqrt(int n)
{
    for (int i = 1, j = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        n -= j;
        j += 2;
        if (n == j)return i + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I read that `<<` has higher precedence than '?' and ':', so I put it inside parentheses, but that didn't help.

How can I output one of two different types without needing to use an `if` statement with two different `cout` statements?

Comment: As the error is telling you the types you'd get from `___0607sqrt(a) : "?"` are different - and they are not allowed to be. This has nothing to do with `std::cout`

Comment: What are you asking? What you posted doesn't make much sense.

Comment: aside: `___0607sqrt` is a reserved name, so please choose a different name

Comment: How is `___0607sqrt` a reserved name?   I googled it and it didn't come up with anything other than this page. Or are you referring to the fact that the two leading underscores in the name are designations as reserved?

Comment: @selbie "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica -- I don't know who you're quoting, but that's not quite right. Identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter and identifiers that **contain two consecutive underscores** are reserved.

Comment: @PeteBecker Whoops, I quoted the C11 standard instead of the C++11 standard.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica -- ah, that makes sense. I haven't thought about reserved names in C in a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the type of this expression?

```
((___0607sqrt(a) != 0) ? ___0607sqrt(a) : "?")
```

Is it an `int` or a `char*` ?  The compiler doesn't know either.

The compiler needs the expression to the left of the `:` to be of the same type or or convertible as the expression to the right of the `:` in the ternary.

Better:

```
cout << "sqrt(" << a << ") = " << ((___0607sqrt(a) != 0) ? std::to_string(___0607sqrt(a)) : "?");
```

You may need to `#include <string>` for the `std::to_string` declaration.